# Calculated Field - parsing out First and Last Name from Active Directory Field

Tags: active-directory, calculated-column

I want to parse out the "Assigned To" field which is populated by our Active Directory into First Name and Last Name. 
Can someone please provide the syntax for that? Step by step?

Many thanks!

Comment: You aren't going to be able to. Calculated columns see person and group fields as domain\username or as a claim. This will be something you have to set via workflow or use CSR/JSLink to do.

Comment: Are you just needing to display it in a view? Or in a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

As Eric said in the comments, Calculated Columns can not reference complex fields (only simple fields like Text and Number, Date)

With CSR you can alter how fields are displayed

```
    AssignedTo: {
        View: function (ctx) {
            var name = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name;
            var value = ctx.CurrentItem[name];
            if(value){
              user=value[0];
              console.warn(user);
              return user.title;
            } else {
              return '';
            }
        }
    }
```